# Build failed with Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lex

While building Lex I'm getting the following error:

> The number of intents and slots exceeds the permissible value for bot
>   "test_dev". A bot can have a maximum of 310 intents and slots. This
>   bot has 63 intents and 253slots.

However, as I can see in the official AWS documentation there is a limit of 1000 intents per account and 100 slots in each account.

Is there a limit that is associated with each bot as well?

Comment: The documentation does not mention these specific bot limits, but that error is pretty clear. For confirmation and nudge to update their documentation, I suggest opening a support ticket with Amazon. Then you can answer this question with their response so we can all get some sort of reference.

Comment: Yes, @JayA.Little, I have opened a ticket on AWS support and they confirmed this is the limit on bot instance. However, they can increase the limit at their end if required.

Comment: Good to know! Please do write that as an answer here, and you can quote their response. You can also mark your own answer as correct so that the question doesn't look open and others can find the answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a ticket to AWS and got the below response from them:

> Usually, an error of this type occurs when the sum of the number of
>   slots and intents for a Lex bot has exceeded the value of 310. Looking
>   at the observed error, I see that you have 253 slots and 63 intents,
>   when these numbers are combined they sum up to 316 and they exceed the
>   maximum limit of 310. Therefore, the limit of 310 is breached and
>   hence the error is observed.
>
> To address your question regarding limits for Lex bots, yes, there are
>   limits that are applicable to bots only as discussed in {1}. I
>   understand your concern about the limit of 1000 intents per account,
>   however, this limit applies at account level and not on a Lex bot
>   level. With that said, I am happy to assist you with submitting a
>   limit request for an increase on the number of intents and slots for
>   your bot. For the request to be fulfilled, I would appreciate if you
>   could provide me with the following information:
>
> 1. A use case stating the reasons for the limit request.
> 2. Please confirm the number of slots and number of intents you wish these values to be increased to.
> 3. Please confirm that limit increase for the Lex bot ‘test’ in the eu-west-1 region.'